# npm ERR! when installing ethereumjs-testrpc in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: testrpc, ethereumjs

```
'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=/home/uspace/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git /home/uspace/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-github-com-debris-bignumber-js-git-master-df3f1ce1: remote: Invalid username or password.
npm ERR! git clone --template=/home/uspace/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror //github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git /home/uspace/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-github-com-debris-bignumber-js-git-master-df3f1ce1: fatal: Authentication failed for '//github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git/'
npm ERR! Linux 4.8.0-56-generic
npm ERR! argv "/opt/node/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ethereumjs-testrpc"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --template=/home/uspace/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror//github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git /home/uspace/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-github-com-debris-bignumber-js-git-master-df3f1ce1
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository '/home/uspace/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-github-com-debris-bignumber-js-git-master-df3f1ce1'...
npm ERR! remote: Invalid username or password.
npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed for '//github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git/'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <//github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/uspace/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Note that https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js doesn't exist - looks like it might have been made private...

Comment: @RichardHorrocks There was a nasty bug affecting IOS bignumber.js (https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/issues/120), web3 has a dependency on that old fork of bignumber.js and it was affected.

Comment: The workaround from @dylanseago https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/332 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is being tracked by the following tickets:

- `web3` - https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/470
- `npm` - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17413

I'd suggesting following these for resolution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the ticket details which are open. I am tracking them to find a resolution or workaround if any